# Vimeo API: Anyway to get a user's follower count?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, vimeo, vimeo-api

I've done a lot of googling and can't seem to find any way to get a user's number of followers from the Vimeo API.  I'm building in Rails and have authentication through omniauth-vimeo working.  I have also tried using the vimeo gem but it doesn't seem to have any response that provides follower count.

It seems like the only option is screen-scraping but I would prefer not too.

Does anyone know of a way to get a user's number of followers on Vimeo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you request all of a users followers (/users/[id or name]/followers) the collection information provides the total amount of followers.

In version 3.2, this will also be on the user response, under the "followers" connection.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues using the API. I built a PHP function to grab the follower count from anyones Vimeo channel with NO API. It's been working for me for more than a year (script called and follow count dumped into database via cron job every 15 minutes for more than a year and never missed a beat).

```
##########################
// Get Vimeo Followers //
##########################
function getVimeoFollowers($url){
    $file = fopen($url,"rb");
    if (!$file)
        return "";
    while (feof ($file)===false) {
        $line = fgets ($file, 1024);
        $content .= $line;
    }
    fclose($file);

    $start = strpos($content,'"followers"')+13;
    $end = strpos($content,'","videos"',$start+1);
    $output = substr($content,$start,$end-$start);
    return $output;
}
```

And then simply call it with the Vimeo channel url:

```
$VimeoFollowers = getVimeoFollowers("https://vimeo.com/USERNAME");
```

Let me know how you get on :)

Cheers

Andy